# Javascript redirect with hash after replacing history state to the same path

Tags: javascript, redirect, backbone.js

I have two backbone model change events that occur at the same time:

1. `change:path` replaces current history state and patches some links
   on the page,
2. `change:language` should redirect to the new path with additional hash

Redirection should supersede replacing state, but this doesn't happen if hash is provided. I'm trying to make it work in Chrome.

This code doesn't redirect:

```
// in change:path event
window.history.replaceState({state: 1}, "", "/new_path");

// in change:language event
window.location.replace("/new_path#hash");
```

But without hash it works as expected:

```
// in change:path event
window.history.replaceState({state: 1}, "", "/new_path");

// in change:language event
window.location.replace("/new_path");
```

Is there any way to make it work with hash? I know I can add some timestamp to make new url totally different, but I want url to be clean.

Comment: have you tried URLencoding the # sign as %23

Comment: I've just tried it, encoding # as %23 makes it part of the path.

Comment: Instead of `window.location.replace("/new_path#yourHash");`, could you just change the hash like this:  `window.location.hash = "yourHash";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to solve it in a not-so-clean way but I'm still looking for the better solution:

```
// change:path event
window.history.replaceState({state: 1}, "", "/new_path");

// change:language event
setTimeout(function(){
  // make sure it runs after replaceState in change:path
  window.history.replaceState({}, "", "/"); 
  window.location.replace("/new_path#hash");
}, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the best way is to not use the `replace` method, but to just set the location as a whole.  Like this:

```
window.location.href = 'http://www.sitename.com/new_path#hash';
```

Comment: It doesn't redirect after replaceState call.

Comment: You may try it yourself, open console and run this code: `window.history.replaceState({state: 1}, "", "/new_path"); window.location.href = window.location.origin + "/new_path#hash";` it won't redirect.

Comment: I did and it did work.  What version of Chrome are you using?  The reason that I ask is that a while back there was a version that had some weirdness with the hash  http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=78839

Comment: I'm using the latest Chrome for OS X and this code only replaces location and does not redirect the page.

Comment: `replaceState` AFTER you redirect using `window.location.href`. Since you're attempting to replace the history state with the url you're going to, you should be able to grab the "current" url on the next page on page load, and replace the history state with it.

Comment: replaceState MAY be unnecessary, maybe someone else can clarify, but I believe that the history state should be "logged" when you get to the next page anyways. Could be completely off here though...

Comment: I don't need to keep the state. And I don't know how to ensure that backbone change events are called in the right order. I need to replace the state when path is changed and redirect if language is changed, but when language is changed, path is also changed (they both come from server in json format).

Comment: And by the way, changing the order to `window.location.replace("/new_path#hash");
window.history.replaceState({state: 1}, "", "/new_path");` also doesn't redirect.